# How to get data from properties file inside JavaScript in a maven dynamic web project

Tags: javascript, maven, jsp, web, dynamic

My project is a maven dynamic web project. I have a drop-down for usernames and a text box for password in JSP file. Based on the selection of the user name in the drop-down, I need to auto-fill corresponding password in the text box. The mapping of username and password is from properties file.

```
login.properties
username1=password1
username2=password2
username3=password3
```

The properties file is directly in src/main/resources folder. 
The jsp file is directly in WebContent folder.

Attached image contains a snippet of form elements in JSP file and the JavaScript. The username drop down options are dynamically populated using another JavaScript which works fine.

[Code snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IeqVx.png)

Also, I tried using below code but unable to provide right path.

```
var props = new java.util.Properties();
props.load(new java.io.FileInputStream("login.properties"));     
var password = props.getProperty(account);
```

Is it possible to access properties file inside this JavaScript code? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I don't think it is possible. Js run in client-side but your properties file in server-side. If you use ajax, i think you can get it, but i think it not ok.

Comment: Ok. Is it possible to achieve it using JSP code?

Comment: The key is to realize, **where** and **when** which code is executed - JSP on the server, when the page is requested and rendered (i.e. **before** the response is sent to the browser), and Javascript in the browser, **after** the browser receives the **already generated** response.

Comment: This is for the scenario where the page is rendered before the response is sent to the browser.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround. Since I am unable to format the code even after using {} button, I have provided the code as an image.

[Code snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dos3H.png)